# Can "AbortController" be used as a functional alternative to "removeEventListener"?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've just learnt that in modern browsers one can cancel events handlers permanently via [AbortSignal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal).

Here's a small proof-of-concept (checkout [this pen](https://codepen.io/schahen/pen/wvJVJMM) for a demo):

```js
let container = () => document.getElementById('container');
let cancelButton = () => document.getElementById('cancel');

function main() {  
 let controller = new AbortController();
 let signal = controller.signal;

  container().addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("I'm being clicked!!!");
  }, {signal});
  
  cancelButton().addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Ha ha!!! Your yellow square event is cancelled!!!');

     controller.abort();
     container().innerText = "click me no more";
 });
}
```

This works. However, docs are stating following:

> The AbortController interface represents a controller object that
> allows you to abort one or more Web requests as and when desired.

That said, it nowhere in documentation it is stated that:

1. **AbortController** can be applied to any arbitrary event (in the doc following terminology is used - DOM requests, Web requests).
2. Consequences of its usage are exact equivalent of calling 'removeEventListener'.

So my question is - **can I use **AbortController** as a functional alternative to `removeEventListener`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters) (`options` parameter -> `signal`) - yes, you can use `AbortSignal.abort()` as an alternative to `removeEventListener` since:

> The listener will be removed when the given AbortSignal’s abort() method is called.

Comment: According to this article it's not the case for all browsers  - https://css-tricks.com/using-abortcontroller-as-an-alternative-for-removing-event-listeners/

Comment: @shabunc it's certanly not. [`AbortSignal.abort()` itself is not that widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal#browser_compatibility).